# Batch file ends unexpectedly. Has been working for years but has suddenly stopped working

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which hids a folder. It has been working for years but has suddenly stopped working and I can't work out why.

```
@ECHO OFF
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDPrivate
:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure you want to lock this folder? (Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM
:LOCK
ren Private "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End
:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock Your Secure Folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%== takingcareofbusiness goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Private
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End
:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end
:MDPrivate
md Private
echo Private created successfully
goto End
:End
```

The problem initially presents as a problem with the attrib settings not being applied in the LOCK section but on further investigation (putting an echo after the ren command), the batch file closes after the ren command.

What's even more weird is that is runs perfectly well in Command Prompt but not when running it from Windows Explorer.

User has Administrator priviledge but it just stops working.

Comment: Oh, please assign that string to a variable - `set "secure=Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"` - then you can use `%secure%` in place of that saga. Makes it much easier if you change the name or clone the file for some other directory. It certainly looks like a privileges issue - try `echo %username%&pause` before the `ren` to absolutely check on the username under both conditions - from-the-prompt and from-explorer. Does the `ren` complain? A `pause` after the `ren` line should reveal any comment that `ren` has to make.

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested as I am not even on my Windows device. but some things to note. Do not use `set /p` when dealing with choice selection. You can use `choice.exe` for that.

When comparing items using `if` always follow the trend on both sides by matching exactly between double quotes. i.e `if "var" == "%var%"`

```
@ECHO OFF
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST "Private" goto MDPrivate

choice /c yn /m "echo Are you sure you want to lock this folder?"
if errorlevel 2 goto :EOF

ren "Private" "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto :EOF

:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock Your Secure Folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT "%pass%" == "takingcareofbusiness" goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" "Private"
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto :EOF
:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto :EOF
:MDPrivate
md Private
echo Private created successfully
```